# What is the matrix element of b24?

Tags: matrices

*I'm just learning about matrices and I am confused by this question. If there are similar questions, please comment the link to that, thanks!*

$$\boldsymbol{B}=\begin{bmatrix}8 & –6 & 10 & –4 & 2\\–15 &–7 &12 &25 &–24\\–5 &–23 &9 &–25 &–9 
\end{bmatrix}$$
The question was **"Find the matrix element $b_{24}$."** The answer was $25$, I'm just unsure how. If you can explain it, that would be great!

Comment: row 2, column 4

Comment: $A_{i,j}$ refers to the $i$'th row, $j$'th column entry of the matrix $A$ (*or at times $a_{i,j}$, replacing the upper case letter for the matrix with the corresponding lowercase letter*).  At times people will be lazy and not include a comma, which might be the source of your confusion.  It should be read "$b$ - two - four" as opposed to "$b$-twentyfour."  In order to emphasize the fact that it is row followed by column, you will never hear me say the words row and column in the opposite order (unless unavoidable).  Similarly, examples might use Robbers and Cops, Rum Runners and Coastguard...